# CGAffineTransformTranslate meaning and the values set during transformation

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

I've seen various pieces of code that does Affine transformation and they tend to always
invoke CGAffineTransformTranslate with some coordinate values.

Typical code looks like:

```
CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, +80.0, +100.0);
```

Apple doc's on CGAffineTransformTranslate says,

> You use this function to create a new
>   affine transform by adding translation
>   values to an existing affine
>   transform. The resulting structure
>   represents a new affine transform,
>   which you can use (and reuse, if you
>   want) to move a coordinate system.

I've played around with different values for tx and ty but can someone tell what it actually means? That is, if I put in 80, 100, then what does that exactly mean in comparison to putting in 20, 40?

Answer (score 1):

Translation means moving around. An affine transform that includes a (80; 100) translation component will move whatever is transformed by it (e.g. vector, point) by 80 on the X axis and 100 axis, *after* rotation and scaling are applied.

What a translation of 1 means is a different story altogether. It might be 1 pixel, or some arbitrary unit dependent on the projection transform used (if talking 3D).

Comment: So basically after you're rotated it (not sure whether the center or a corner serves as an axis), you need to bring back the top-left corner back to an x,y axis to realign the item that was rotated?

Comment: The center of rotation is usually called the origin, and it's always the (0,0) point. If a rotated object's corner is at (0,0) then the object will rotate around the corner. If the object's center is at (0,0), then it will rotate around the center. The origin can be set by applying a translation transform before a rotation transform. I'm not sure what you mean by 'realign'.